# jQuery scroll, my page back through the top

Tags: jquery, scroll

I tried to create a smooth scroll when we click on a circle on my menu the page scroll until the corresponding section. But when we click several times on a circle the page seems to come back through the top of my page before to go on the right section. Why ?

Due to the structure of my page $('html, body') doesn't works I must use $('#page')

To see : click several times on the circle 2 or 3: http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/FtaL3/6/

```
$('.navbar a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('#page').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

Comment: The second time you click the elements offset is zero, so it scrolls to the top. This probably happens because  you attached the scrollbar to #page, and not the body/html

Comment: Oh ok but due to the structure of my page body/html doesn't works, I don't know why.